# How to use Android NDK SQLite3 extension json1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, sqlite-json1

I am sorry that I lack English first.

I compiled it because I needed SQLite3 extension JSON1 in Android NDK

```
gcc -Os -I. -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0     -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1             \
   -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=0       -DSQLITE_USE_ALLOCA               \
   -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_WAL_SYNCHRONOUS=1 -DSQLITE_LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS  \
   -DSQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH=0          -DSQLITE_OMIT_DECLTYPE            \
   -DSQLITE_OMIT_PROGRESS_CALLBACK    -DSQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE        \
   -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED           -DHAVE_USLEEP     -DHAVE_READLINE \
   shell.c sqlite3.c -ldl -lreadline -lncurses -o sqlite3
```

and result of compile is sqlite3.exe

how to use this file for Anroid NDK
or can I find other way?

The code I want to use

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_test_ndkapp_MainActivity_SQLiteCPP(
        JNIEnv *jenv,
        jobject self,
        jstring database_path
){
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    // jstring to const char *
    const char *database = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(database_path, 0);

    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    //SQL ERROR:no such function: json
    const char * create_sql = "create table user(name, phone)";
    const char * insert_sql = "insert into user (name, phone) values(\"oz\", json('{\"cell\":\"+491765\", \"home\":\"+498973\"}'))";
    const char * select_sql = "select json_extract(user.phone, '$.cell') from user";

    if (sqlite3_open_v2(database, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE , NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        LOGE("database open!!");

        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, create_sql, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);

        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
            LOGE("SQL ERROR:%s", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        } else {
            LOGE("CREATE Operation done successfully\n");
        }

        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, insert_sql, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);

        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
            LOGE("SQL ERROR:%s", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        } else {
            LOGE("INSERT Operation done successfully\n");
        }

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, select_sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
            LOGE("SQL ERROR:%s", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        } else {
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                const unsigned char * aaa           = sqlite3_column_text (stmt, 0);
                const unsigned char * bbb           = sqlite3_column_text (stmt, 1);

                LOGE("%s, %s", aaa, bbb);
            }

            if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
                LOGE("error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }

            LOGE("SELECT Operation done successfully\n");

            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }

    } else {
        LOGE("database can not open!! : %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I tried this
just put .c file and .h file in cpp folder → SQLite3 is worked but no such function json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need libsqlite3, not an executable, so you don't need to compile **shell.c**. There is a GitHub [project](https://github.com/stockrt/sqlite3-android) that includes the **Android.mk** that creates such library for you, you will probably find the [static library](https://github.com/stockrt/sqlite3-android/blob/master/jni/Android.mk#L15) easier to use in your JNI project.

Comment: Your answer was of great help. I got libsqlite3.so and .a files and the answer to your other writing was helpful during the process. Now I will try to use it at CmakeList.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how you can use JSON1 by adding a Flag in an environment that uses CMakeLists if you develop NDK in AndroidStudio.

First, download sqlite-amalgamation-(the version you want).zip
and unzip .zip file
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (Download link)

Place the 4 files you have obtained on the desired path in the cpp directory of the project.

[The path to the file that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT8Zq.png)

Then add code to CMakeList.txt.

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
         src/main/cpp/sqlite/shell.c
         src/main/cpp/sqlite/sqlite3.c
         src/main/cpp/sqlite/sqlite3.h
         src/main/cpp/sqlite/sqlite3ext.h
    )

....

add_definitions( -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 )
```

Now you can use the JSON1 functions of SQLite3.

```
const char * create_sql = "create table user(name, phone)";
const char * insert_sql = "insert into user (name, phone) values(\"oz\", json('{\"cell\":\"+491765\", \"home\":\"+498973\"}'))";
const char * select_sql = "select json_extract(user.phone, '$.cell') from user";
```